# Transact sql : must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to iterate over some tables and clear all records.

My code is the following :

```html
DECLARE @table varchar(100)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR select name from sys.tables where name like '%cfe_%'
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @table

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       print @table        
    delete from @table
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @table   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

But I receive "Must declare the table variable "@table" at the line "delete..."

I can't see the error.

Thank you

Comment: because you can't do a delete from a table variable inside a cursor. Use a temp table instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud use dynamic query,

```
DECLARE @table varchar(100)
        ,@v_str nvarchar(200)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR select name from sys.tables where name like '%cfe_%'
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @table

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       print @table   

       set   @v_str = 'delete from '+@table   

       exec(@v_str)

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @table   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Unless the underscore is wrapped in square brackets this will return any table with the characters cfe, it will ignore the underscore because it is treated as a wildcard for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic delete statement... Try this :

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @table varchar(100)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR select name from sys.tables where name like '%cfe_%'
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @table

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       SET @cmd = 'DELETE FROM '+@table       
       EXEC (@cmd)
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @table   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

Even better would be to not use a cursor here. Looping in sql is a last resort. Also, your query is not going to do exactly what you think it will because you are using like and wanting to find an underscore. The underscore in a LIKE predicate requires it to be escaped with square brackets. As posted your query will return any table with cfe in the name not cfe_.

Once you are comfortable that the dynamic sql string is what you want you can uncomment it to execute it.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'delete from ' + name + ';'
from sys.tables
where name like '%cfe[_]%'

select @SQL
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

---

We can also use while loop for this process

```
DECLARE @Min Int,@max Int
IF Object_id('Tempdb..#DeleteList')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #DeleteList

CREATE TABLE #DeleteList (Id Int Identity,Name varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #DeleteList(Name)
SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE CHARINDEX('cfe_',name)>0
SELECT @Min=Min(Id) FROm #DeleteList
SELECT @max=MAX(Id) FROm #DeleteList

While(@Min<=@max)
Begin
Declare @TableName Varchar(50),
        @Sql Nvarchar(max)
SELECT @TableName=Name From #DeleteList Where id=@Min

SET @Sql='DELETE From '+@TableName
Exec (@Sql)
SET @Min=@Min+1
END
```

---

But if the deleting tables have foreign key refrences it will throw error so that first you need delete records from child and then go to Parent table

Answer (score -1):

You will need to do something like;

```
EXEC sp_executesql @statement = N'DELETE FROM ' + @table
```

because currently you are trying to delete from a String variable, not the table named the same as the variable